# Find Unique Value and attach all related values in Array of Objects

Tags: python, arrays, django, python-3.x, object

I want to create an array of objects. I have all the variables and need to just format all the values.

These are my values:

```
url =  "Goodreads",
search = "Fantasy",
search_res = [
        {
            "book": "Harry Potter",
            "rating": "10.0"
        },
        {
            "book": "Lord of The Rings",
            "rating": "9.0"
        }
]
url =  "GoodReads",
search = "Dystopia",
search_res = [
        {
            "book": "Handmaids Tale",
            "rating": "9.0"
        },
        {
            "book": "Divergent Series",
            "rating": "8.5"
        }
]
url =  "Kindle",
search = "Fantasy",
search_res = [
        {
            "book": "Twilight Series",
            "rating": "5.5"
        },
        {
            "book": "A Discovery of Witches",
            "rating": "8.5"
        }
]
url =  "Kindle",
search = "Dystopia",
search_res = [
        {
            "book": "Hunger Games",
            "rating": "9.5"
        },
        {
            "book": "Maze Runner",
            "rating": "6.0"
        }
]
```

My code:

```
    assign_url = url
    the_list = []
    urls = { 
        'the_url' : assign_url,
        'results' : []
    }

    data['search'] = search
    data['results'] = search_res
    urls['results'].append(data)
    the_list.append(urls)
    pprint(json.dumps(the_list))
```

My Result:

```
 ('[{"the_url": "GoodReads", "results": [{"search": "Fantasy", ''"results": [{"book": "Harry Potter", "Rating": "10.0"}, {"book": "Lord of The Rings", "Rating": "9.0"}]}]}]')
 ('[{"the_url": "GoodReads", "results": [{"search": "Dystopia", ''"results": [{"book": "Handmaids Tale", "Rating": "9.0"}, {"book": "Divergent Series", "Rating": "8.5"}]}]}]')
 ('[{"the_url": "Kindle", "results": [{"search": "Fantasy", ''"results": [{"book": "Twilight Series", "Rating": "5.5"}, {"book": "Divergent Series", "Rating": "8.5"}]}]}]')
 ('[{"the_url": "Kindle", "results": [{"search": "Dystopia", ''"results": [{"book": "Hunger Games", "Rating": "9.5"}, {"book": "A Discovery of Witches", "Rating": "8.5"}]}]}]')
```

I want to be able to group the results by the_url and format it such:

Expected Result:

```
            the_list = [{
              url : "GoodReads",
              results : [{
                search : "Fantasy",
                search_res : [{
                  "book": "Harry Potter",
                  "rating": "10.0"
                }, {
                  "book": "Lord of The Rings",
                  "rating": "9.0"
                }]
              }, {
                search : "Dystopia",
                search_res : [{
                  "book": "Handmaids Tale",
                  "rating": "9.0"
             Dystopia
                  "book": "Divergent Series",
                  "rating": "8.5"
                }]
              }]
            }, {
              url : "Kindle",
              results : [{
                search : "Fantasy",
                search_res : [{
                  "book": "Twilight Series",
                  "rating": "5.5"
                }, {
                  "book": "A Discovery of Witches",
                  "rating": "8.5"
                }]
              }, {
                search : "Dystopia",
                search_res : [{
                  "book": "Hunger Games",
                  "rating": "9.5"
                }, {
                  "book": "Maze Runner",
                  "rating": "6.0"
                }]
              }]
            }, ]
```

Is there anyway for me to group this by url? How can I fix my code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: But that is not valid Python or JSON syntax.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, that is my bad. I will change the = to . These are objects in an array and search_res is another array with objects in them again

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have fixed it now. Please tale a look